# MapReduce pairwise comparison of all lines in multiple files

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

I'm getting started with using python's [mrjob](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/) to convert some of my long running python programs into MapReduce hadoop jobs. I've gotten the simple word count examples to work and I conceptually understand the 'text-classification' example.

However, I'm having a little trouble figuring out the steps I need to do to get my problem working.

I have multiple files (about 6000) each of which have 2 to 800 lines each. In this case each line is a simple space-delimited 'signal'. I need to compare correlation between each line in each file and EVERY other line in ALL files (including itself). Then based on the correlation coefficient I'll output the results.

An example of one file:

```
1 2 3 4 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2
2 2 3 1 3 3 1 2 3 1 4 1
2 3 4 5 3 2 1 3 4 5 2 1
...
```

I need to yield each LINE of this file paired with EVERY OTHER LINE from every other file ... or I could concatenate all files into one file if that makes things easier, but I would still need the pairwise iteration.

I understand how to do the calculation and how to use the final reduce step to aggregate and filter the results. The difficulty I'm having is how to I `yield` all pairwise items to successive steps without reading all files in a single setp? I guess I could prepare an input file ahead of time which uses `itertools.product` but this file would be prohibitively large.

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Comment: Sure, just added some :)

Comment: maybe I could use a `reduce` step first and give all of the lines the same key so the function gets all lines ... then use `itertools.product` to `yield` all pairs with the proper keys. Not sure if this is the right way to do things though.

Comment: If you have an O(n^2) algorithm and n is approximately 600 000, I'd recommend you look for an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: Sadly this is already well reduced from original number of items ... but in general N is about 40,000. I have run it on my single machine to completion in about ~4 days ... So its not outside the realm of reasonableness.

Comment: Again, when your original conception of the problem leads to an algorithm with a 4-day runtime, the answer is not to use Hadoop/map-reduce but to find an algorithmic change to reduce the problem complexity. I can't really say I understand what you are doing, but that is my general observation.

Comment: Essentially each "signal" comes from a region of an "aligned genome" where (in this example) each "column" represents an individual and each row represents a position in that genome. The idea is that regions which interact (physically bind) have higher mutual correlation. To test this I need to calculate the correlation between ALL pairs and see if TRUE interactors (which I have from other methods) have a higher correlation (on average) then non-interactors. So there's no way around calculating all pairs without comprimising statistical relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since nobody has come up with an answer I'll post my current work-around in-case anybody else out there needs it. I'm not sure how 'canocical' or efficient this is but its worked so far.

I put the filename as the first item of each line of the file followed by a `\t` followed by the rest of the data. For this example I'm just using a single number on each line and then averaging them, just as a very trivial example.

Then I made the following map-reduce step in `mrjob`.

```
class MRAvgPairwiseLines(MRJob):

def input_mapper(self, _, value):
    """Takes each input line and converts it to (fnum, num) and a key of 'ALL'"""

    fnum, val = value.split('\t')
    yield 'ALL', (fnum, val)

def input_reducer(self, key, values):

    for (fnum1, val1), (fnum2, val2) in product(values, repeat = 2):
        yield fnum1, (fnum1, fnum2, val1, val2)

def do_avg(self, key, value):

    fnum1, fnum2, val1, val2 = value
    res = (float(val1)+float(val2))/float(2)
    yield key, (fnum2, res)

def get_max_avg(self, key, values):

    max_fnum, max_avg = max(values, key = lambda x: x[1])
    yield key, (max_fnum, max_avg)

def steps(self):
    return [self.mr(mapper=self.input_mapper, reducer=self.input_reducer),
                self.mr(mapper=self.do_avg, reducer=self.get_max_avg)]
```

This way all of the output from the `input_mapper` function gets grouped to the same `input_reducer` which then `yield`s successive pairs. These then pass through to the proper places to finally return the largest average (which is actually the largest item in all other files).

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: So you end up loading the entire cartesian product into memory?